# Gcd(f,g)=1 can we express the entire ring of polynomials using f and g?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

If we have 2 polynomials f and g over a field F and the gcd(f,g)=1 can we represent every polynomial with coefficients in F as a liner combination of f and g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: can you represent $1$ as a linear combination of $f$ and $g$? Can you construct other polynomials from your solution for $1$?

Comment: I can construct 1 with f and g, but don't know about if I can represent every polynomial

Comment: If you have a solution for $1$, say, $af + bg = 1$ for some polynomials $a$ and $b$, then you can simply multiply both sides by $c$ to get a solution for a polynomial $c$, i.e. $(ac)f+(bc)g=c$.